# Flow Controller Unit Test

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, flow

I have a Visualforce page and controller that calls a flow.  I have only been able to get 7% test coverage.  Is it possible to get more coverage even though you can't start the flow?

Visualforce Page:

```
 <apex:page Controller="QuoteFlowController"> 
    <flow:interview name="Q2C_Quote" interview="{!myFlow}" finishlocation="   {!QID}"/>  
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class QuoteFlowController {
    public Flow.Interview.Q2C_Quote myFlow {get; set;}

public String getmyID() {  
   string returnURL = null;
    if(myFlow!=null){
        if(myFlow.varReview==true){
            returnURL = '/'+ myFlow.varOppID;
        }
        else if(myFlow.varServiceOnly==true){
             returnURL='/'+ myFlow.varQuoteID;
        }
        else{
            returnURL= '/'+ myFlow.varQuoteID+'/e?retURL=/'+myFlow.varQuoteID;
        }
    }
    return returnURL;
}

public PageReference getQID(){   
    PageReference p = new PageReference(getmyID());
    p.setRedirect(true);
    return p;
    }
}
```

Unit Test:

```
@isTest (SeeAllData=true)
public class QuoteFlowControllerTest {
    static testMethod void QuoteFlowTest(){
        PageReference pageRef = Page.RedirectQuote;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);

        QuoteFlowController qfc = new QuoteFlowController();
        qfc.myFlow = new Flow.Interview.Q2C_Quote(new Map<String, Object>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: [Unit Test for Controller that Calls a Flow](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73882/unit-test-for-controller-that-calls-a-flow)

Comment: Based on the related, it seems there is no way to test this?

Comment: "I'm assuming your flow is an interactive flow? If so, you can't test it. If it is a trigger-ready flow, then you need to use the start() method to trigger the flow."

Comment: It is an interactive flow.  Thank you for your help.